# How can I add a service disconnect between main panel breaker and load side

Tags: circuit-breaker

I am working on a small shop and installed a 30amp plugin type breaker to the main breaker panel.

Now the shop has load of a 230v ac Single phase motor, some lights and outlets.

I wanted to add a disconnect to the 30 amp breaker and my tools (motors,c-outlet,lights) in the shop specifically because the main service panel is a but far for me to got back and forth in case and just for me to work on things without going to the service panel. Can I put a fuse box and just wire up a single fuse to the line side , no fuse on neutral (we have 2 lines, live and neutral wire.) And make the fuse box as a service disconnect.

Knife switch isn't my go, no good for sparks, corrosion as well.

Btw I do have ground, directly into the chassis of the motor.

Comment: Providing pictures of the panel(s) in question, with the covers off and the breakers involved identified would help a lot. [Edit] your post, then drag the clear, focused pictures into the text edit box - the system will upload and host them for you.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: I'm completely with @ThreePhaseEel  where is the OP on this planet? It makes a big difference. I grimaced in horror when the OP mentioned fuses and knife switches...taking us back 75-100 years. Also, more info as to what the "motor" is doing and more info about the shop would be helpful

Comment: Without a location a proper solution can not be provided. I believe this is a hot and neutral and a properly rated safety switch may be appropriate. Almost every industrial motor in the US has a knife switch @george Anderson some are fused, or circuit breaker but most industrial motor systems require a disconnect and knife switches with a snap action are about the only way to meet the code requirements for lockout tag out. See exhibits 430.16 & 17 in the NEC for examples of this. Or 430.102.B.1

Comment: > EFL > 30A not 32A > 230V ... I detect Australia/New Zealand.

Answer (score -1):

The electricians will be along shortly. My recommendation would be a "non-fused safety switch" that can be bought at any electrical store, Lowes, Home Depot, or most any hardware type store, as long as you are feeding the power from a circuit breaker from the main panel. You may be better off by running a heavy wire from the main panel breaker and adding a small circuit breaker panel in the shop area that can be further broken down into individual 120/240 volt circuits.  You wrote that (we have 2 lines, live and neutral wire) which needs to be better explained since you don't get 240 volts from 1 wire + a neutral. The electricians will explain your needs better than I can.

Comment: Hot and neutral provides 240V basically everywhere in the world except US/Canada. Places where Home Depot and Lowe’s don’t exist.

Comment: That's true, @nobody, but there are equivalents. B&Q in the UK, Bunnings in Australia`*`, for example. I'm sure most countries have something similar. `*`(just names I'm familiar with, not recommendations, or slights against other brands)

Comment: Yeah, we have only 2 lines out here for residential connection. Wires used are called service drops which has an uncoated aluminium wire and a Coated one going to the entrance. Ahh okay so it's fine to like Doing parallel breakers . One from the distribution panel and another one to the Shop. Then that will like a secondary sub panel basically for lights, outlets, etc.

Comment: We don't have home depot here but there are alot of commercial hardware stores.

Comment: If the op was in the US the down vote could be warranted because the op The OP did not provide location, additional comments possibly provide this is a hot and neutral but without that information I reversed the down vote.